# Reading and then using an array from a web source in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, ajax

A web page source is gotten by the following:

```
$.ajax({ url: 'your-url', success: function(data) { ...my commands... } });
```

The "data" has an array somewhere in its text, like:

```
var MyArray=[1, 2, 3];
```

My question is how should I read "MyArray" and its elements from data and set it as an array?
The numbers in "MyArray" can be anything, but the web page always has "var MyArray=[#1,...,#N];" somewhere in its source.

Comment: Could you share the output of the `data` variable?

Comment: Avoid working with unpredictable responses, since they might break the application someday. What kind of service are you calling?

Comment: It is a long html! You may use the following URL to get it: 'http://www.tsetmc.com/Loader.aspx?ParTree=15131P&i=12638840758449459&d=20190916' and my interest is one of the arrays at the end of it. @EmielZuurbier

Comment: Sorry, I can't get what you mean by "service"? @briosheje

Comment: @SamYahaghi I've checked your link. You should to do this another way. HTML does not have any `arrays`, only JavaScript has those. What you need is to get the raw data in the form of **JSON**. I think that is what *briosheje* means by a "service". A service to get the data from. The same data that is used in the site. Maybe they have an API. That seems worth checking out.

Comment: @SamYahaghi where are you fetching the data from? what is being returned?

Comment: The link has been given in the above comments, please find it. @briosheje

Comment: I think it should be possible to convert HTML text to Javascript arrays. Am I wrong? @EmielZuurbier

Comment: You are not wrong. It is possible, but you really have to know what you are looking for. If you know the elements you want to get, then it is no problem. So you could help us by telling **what** elements you are trying to get. Be specific.

Comment: I want to extract the elements of "ClientTypeData" and write them to an array in Javascript. I hope I clarified it because I am not an expert. @EmielZuurbier

Comment: @EmielZuurbier any comments?

Comment: I think you should try to make an attempt first. I could not find `ClientTypeData`, but if you can, then please take that piece of HTML and copy it. Then write your code trying to convert that HTML piece into JavaScript. If you run into any trouble, we can help you from there. Also @MKougiouris gives you a solid pointer as to what you should try. Listen to his advice.

Answer (score 2):

TLDR: Do it in some other way...

Aside from a bunch of reasons to not do something like that ( efficiency, maintainability, "correctness of approach" you could try the following...

You could parse the source as text, execute a regexp test to find something matching the declaration of an array and then continue on from there to parse again the numbers defined in the text using regexp again.

If you know the name of the array that you expect to read then you might have a chance at this, otherwise i would suggest to not even think what i suggest above...

Comment: Well its hard to post some sample relative to you, without you providing us a bit of the html response that you are intrested in, but you could take a look at this https://www.regextester.com/27540
In this example, a regexp is used to parse some content from an html element.
You will have to workout your own regexpressions that will suite your need to locate the needed array definition and parse its text

Answer (score -1):

If you want to GET array from data and move its element to another array:

```
var inst=data.d;
var myArray=[];
for (var i=0; i<inst.length;i++){
    myArray.push(inst[i]);
}
```